# Create a string with the result of an expression and the expression that originated the value. Is it possible?

Tags: java, string

Like

```
String r = SomeThing.toExecString("new Object().toString()");
```

And when executed the value of `r` would be:

```
"new Object().toString() = java.lang.Object@c5e3974"
```

Is this even possible at all? Would it need a bunch of reflection?  A built in compiler maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("beanshell");
Object result = engine.eval("new Object().toString();");
System.out.println(result);
```

You may get close to what you want using BeanShell. I ran the above code with Java 6 with [BeanShell 2.0b4](http://www.beanshell.org/) and the JSR 223-based [bsh-engine.jar engine](https://scripting.dev.java.net/) on the classpath.

Comment: Wow, yeap, something like that.  And then I can have a method: `toExecString( String v ) {  return v  + " = + engine.eval( v ); }` powerful ( and dangerous at the same time ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post here: 
Generating Static Proxy Classes - http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue180.html

Part one is enough for what you asked, I think

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you really wanted this. But your problem would be solved with this method:

```
String toExecString( String code ) {
    return String.format( 
        "\"%s\" = %s@%x", 
        code, 
        code.getClass().getName(), 
        code.hashCode() 
    );
}
```

Comment: 2nd slash should be 1 char to the left.

Comment: Not really I meant, any expression, for instance `toExecString("1+1")` should yield: `1+1 = 2`